# value of string changes after function ends

Tags: c

I'be build this function to convert integers to binary strings

```
char* numberToBinary(int num){
    char arr[11];
    int x=1;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        arr[9 - i] = (num & x)?'1':'0';
        x = x<<1;
    }
    arr[10] = '\0';
    char* res = &arr[0];
    printf("%s\n", res);//prints 0000000100
    return res;
}
printf("%s\n", numberToBinary(4));//prints changeable binary data
```

The problem is inside the function the variable `res` has the correct answer, but it looks like the retrieved value from the function `I guess` is the location of the variable res, which has been de-located from memory.

How can I make the function `numberToBinary` return a string inside of something else.

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable. This is a grave mistake which your compiler should've warned you about.

Comment: `char arr[11];` --> `static char arr[11];`

Comment: Also, UB aside, you can just change that to `printf("%s\n", arr);`. In this case, `arr` will decay to a pointer to its first element (`char*`) and that will `printf` just fine .. no need for `res`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is the usage assumed by OP. (Make a copy if necessary) note that `printf("%s\n", numberToBinary(4));` will cause a memory leak if memory is secured using `malloc`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I don't see that the OP said they wanted to reuse the same buffer for two completely unrelated calls, and create the crosstalk that would invite in their app.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is the same as reuse you say. In my case it is speculation from the code.

Comment: Change `char arr[11];` to  `static char arr[11];`and `printf("%s\n", res);' to `printf("%s\n", arr);`  finally return `arr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning address of local variable leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), becouse it is not in scope (ended its lifetime) in the time you are passing it to `printf()`.

You have to pass an array to function as parameter, or allocate `char* res` on `heap` (*dynamic storage duration*).

Example

```
char* res = malloc (amountOfBytesYouNeed);
if (res == NULL) { /*err msg*/ exit(-1); }
// Store data to res insted of arr
return res;

//
char * ptr = numberToBinary(4);
printf("%s\n", ptr);
free(ptr); // !
```